# How to disable gz backup history of logs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging

In the /var/log directory from time to time different backup log files are saved, some ending in .1 .2 .3 and .gz. How can I configure the system to generate a single log without making backups but at the same time have a limit?, eg last 1000 records or last month or up to 10mb. It doesn't matter if the records are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `logrotate` configuration.

For example, take a look in the file /etc/logrotate.conf and in the /etc/logrotate.d directory.

Comment: Thanks, i solve this using `rotate 0` in all settings.